# bash script: multitab terminal with different commands in different directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

```
#!/bin/bash

tab="--tab"
foo=""

cmds[1]="'cd /home/eric/project/p1;ls'"
titles[1]="title1"

cmds[2]="'cd /home/eric/project/p2;pwd'"
titles[2]="title2"

cmds[3]="'cd /home/eric/project/p3;dir"
titles[3]="title3"

for i in 1 2 3; do
    foo+=($tab --title="${titles[i]}"  -e "bash -c '${cmds[i]}';bash")
done

gnome-terminal "${foo[@]}"

exit 0
```

This script supposed to open 3 tabs (all for different directories and different commands).
e.g. command1: will change the directory to `/home/eric/project/p1` and will execute command `ls`. Similarly for next 2 commands.

But when I execute this bash script `bash multitab.sh` it opens and immediately closes. I guess there is error thats why this is happening but I cant trace that.

Is there any syntax error?

Comment: Why do you need the `exit 0` at the end?

Comment: try something like this: gnome-terminal --tab --working-directory="/home/eric/project/p1" -e "ls"    Adapt it to your needs

Comment: @Inian without it, the code will exit with the exit value returned by `gnome-terminal`.

Comment: Yes, there are syntax issues with the constructed commands. `bash -c ''cd /home/..;ls'';bash` is not correct. You should see if you can write a `gnome-terminal` command that works manually first before trying to write the script that constructs it.

Comment: See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155551/how-to-debug-a-bash-script) for script-debugging techniques.  First thing is to put `set -x` on the line above the `gnome-terminal` command.  That way you will see what is being executed and can check the gnome-terminal man page to see what's wrong.